# Is there a way to append several values to a Pine Script array in a single call?

Tags: arrays, function, pine-script

I want to have a function within which several *if* conditions looking for specific integer values.

The function in some situations might be called several times in sequence in order to return the resulting values of several different *if* conditions.

The idea I had for this, in order to reduce the code's bulkiness, was to have the portion of the script executing the function as required run through an integer array whose each stored value is sent to the function.

But in order for this to reduce the amount of bulky code I need a way to add several values at once rather than having the values each added separately.

Is that possible in Pinescript? Or perhaps you have a different solution for executing such function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, it seems a simple way to update an array to a set of new values is to use the built in function array.from.

```
var array<int> arr = array.new<int>(0, 0)

arr := array.from(1, 4, 10)
```

It doesn't even require clearing and appending the new values as it simply replaces the testArr array with the new input.

If one wants to append several additional values to an existing array rather than replacing all of the original values, it can be done like this:

```
arr := array.concat(arr, array.from(1, 4, 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you would like a single mass update (addition) to array elements? No such function exists, each element must be individually updated, ideally in a loop if you have a consistent calculation.

Comment: Actually, after some more research it seems I might be able to use a built-in function called array.from to do this.

Comment: to build an array then yes

Comment: Well, that is what I referred to basically. If I one needs to add additional values like this it is possible to update a secondary array using array.from() and then to use array.concat() with the original and secondary array, or to replace a portion of the original values by combining these with array.slice().